# unable to print Html table which contains inputs fields in pdf conversion in angular using jspdf

Tags: html, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

This is the function written in invoice.component.ts file for converting the table to pdf. This is code works fine when the table does not contain any input fields.

```
pdfCreationClick() {
  var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('p','mm','a4');   
  doc.text("this is siva",15,15);
  var element = document.getElementById('secondTable') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
     console.log(canvas)
     var imgWidth = 208;
     var pageHeight = 295;
     var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
     var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth/canvas.width;
     var heightLeft = imgHeight
     doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',0,0,208,imgHeight)
     var position =0;
     doc.save('first.pdf');
  })
}
```

This is the code written in html page i.e invoice.component.html
I had tried to keep the form tag in the place of table tag. Even though also i am not able print the table when it contains input fields.

```
 <table id="secondTable">
            <div class='container' id="rateID">
                <div class='form_row' *ngFor= "let obj of dataarray;let i = index" id="form_row">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class='inline' id='sno'>                
                        <input class='sno' type='text' name='name' value={{i+1}}>
                    </div>            
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='salary{{i}}' [(ngModel)]=obj.product>
                    </div>            
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='age{{i}}' [(ngModel)]=obj.description>
                    </div>            
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='quantity{{i}}' [(ngModel)]=obj.quantity>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='rate{{i}}' (change)='totalAmountChange()' [(ngModel)]=obj.rate>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='amount{{i}}'  [(ngModel)]=obj.rate*obj.quantity>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <input type='text' name='tax{{i}}' [(ngModel)]=obj.tax>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>                            
                        <button class="table_button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
                          </svg></button>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </table>
<button (click)='pdfCreationClick()'>Save and Send</button>
```

This is the HTML content that contains the input fields so after typing the data in input fields if we click on the save, it needs to convert into a pdf page which must contain the table whatever the data I had given.

please help me. I am unable to find the answer, for three days.

any suggestions other than this jspdf also encouraged

Here the issue is not to click event. The main issue is when the table contains the input tags the data which is present in the input tags is not printing in pdf.

Comment: Why don't use just an onclick=""?

Answer (score 0):

Add an on click event in your save button to call your pdf creator function i.e.,

```
<button class="table_button" (click)="pdfCreationClick()">
   ...
</button>
```